# Display in the table if search matches in php

Tags: php

see my Search in php from dat file, This is my code so far:

```
<?php   

if (isset($_POST["name"]))
{

    $file = 'order.dat';
    $searchfor = $_POST["name"];

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.


// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
//$pattern = "/^$pattern/m"; // your string starts with $pattern (177)
$pattern = "/^$pattern.*$/m";



// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
}

?>

    <h3>Search  Order Details</h3>

    <form  method="post" action="search.php"  id="searchform">
      <input  type="text" name="name">
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

order.dat file contains:-

```
175|RC456456456|54156456177|177$

176|RC456456177|54156456177|177$

177|RC456456177|54156456465|129$

178|RC456456456|54156456177|177$
```

now right now if search is found then it says Found matches ... like if i enter 177 the it gives
 `Found matches: 177|RC456456177|54156456465|129$`

now if i enter 002 then it says No matches found

I want to Display in this table if search matches :-

```
<table>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Order number </th>
                    <th>Tranasaction id</th>
                    <th>Date </th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                    </tr>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>


            </table>
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is exactly?

Comment: @David I don't know what your question is either.

Comment: @Pekka see i want to put my data in the table if search matches ... like if i enter 177 it gives Found matches: 177|RC456456177|54156456465|129$ now i want to put that details in the table ... means i want to display this in the table ...

Comment: @Devator :)if search matches .. then-after i want to show the details in the table otherwise no matches found right now alert occur for matches but i want to show 177|RC456456177|54156456465|129$ in the table ...

Comment: @Pekka :) now again question edited for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

You would have to open the file using `fopen` or `file_get_contents`, then you would `explode` or `split` on newlines  `\n` or `\r\n` (depending on OS and file).

Then, you could loop through them and `explode` that string again to see if the first element is what you are looking for. Like so:

```
$resLines = explode("\n", $FileContents);
foreach ($resLines as $line) {
  $resLine = explode("|", $line);
  if ($resLine[0] == $Search) {
    echo "Found! $line";
  }
}
```

**Update regarding your edit**

It would be something like this:

```
$resContents = file_get_contents("order.dat");
$resLines = explode("\n", $FileContents);
    foreach ($resLines as $line) {
      $resLine = explode("|", $line);
      if ($resLine[0] == $Search) {
        $aFound = $resLine; // setting our array with the found contents
      }
}
echo "
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Order number </th>
        <th>Tranasaction id</th>
        <th>Date </th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>" . $aFound[0] . "</td>
        <td>" . $aFound[1] . "</td>
        <td>" . $aFound[2] . "</td>
        <td>" . $aFound[3] . "</td>
    </tr>


</table>";
```

Comment: :) i donot understand what u r saying ... u can chk my coding in any editor it works but still not showing in table