# Display Items in the table if Search matches

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display in the table if search matches in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118497/display-in-the-table-if-search-matches-in-php)

see my Search in php from dat file, This is my code so far:

```
<?php   

if (isset($_POST["name"]))
{

    $file = 'order.dat';
    $searchfor = $_POST["name"];


$contents = file_get_contents($file);

$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

$pattern = "/^$pattern.*$/m";


if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
{
     $result = explode('|', $matches[0]);

}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
}

?>

    <h3>Search  Order Details</h3>

    <form  method="post" action="search.php"  id="searchform">
      <input  type="text" name="name">
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

order.dat file contains:-

```
175|RC456456456|54156456177|177$

176|RC456456177|54156456177|177$

177|RC456456177|54156456465|129$

178|RC456456456|54156456177|177$
```

now right now if search is found then it says Found matches ... like if i enter 177 the it gives
 `Found matches: 177|RC456456177|54156456465|129$`

now if i enter 002 then it says No matches found

```
My Question is
```

I want to Display in this table if search matches :-

```
 <table>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Order number </th>
                    <th>Tranasaction id</th>
                    <th>Date </th>
                    <th>Total Price</th>
                    </tr>

        <td><?=$result[0]?></td>
        <td><?=$result[1]?></td>
        <td><?=$result[2]?></td>
        <td><?=$result[3]?></td>


            </table>
```

Comment: @Baszz :) I want to display in table if search matches

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do something like this :

```
<?php   

    if (isset($_POST["name"])){
        $file = 'order.dat';
        $searchfor = $_POST["name"];
        $contents = file_get_contents($file);
        $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
        $pattern = "/^$pattern.*$/m";
        if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
           $result = implode("\n", $matches[0]);
           $result = explode('|', $result);
        }
        else{
           $result = false;
        }
    }
```

?>

Then display it inside html like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Order number </th>
        <th>Tranasaction id</th>
        <th>Date </th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$result[0]?></td>
        <td><?=$result[1]?></td>
        <td><?=$result[2]?></td>
        <td><?=$result[3]?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: :) no display in td when i m using this but 50% its working

Comment: @David $result is empty ? Where did you add the $result assignation ?

Comment: :) can you plz edit this in your ans ...

Comment: :)when matches it show no results u can also try in your localhost

Comment: what's happen when you make a print_r of it ?

Comment: :) now my code is same as yours but no result given when it matches

Comment: :) still not working question edited

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, tough I think you need to look after the [explode](http://php.net/explode) function:

```
$results = explode("|", $matches[0]);
```

Then you print out the results along with wanted `td` tags.

Comment: :) can u plz edit this in my question

Answer (score 0):

Well...if you have your search result(s), loop through them and output the table row. Maybe the code snippet below can help you. I use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to  get the values.

```
foreach($results as $result){
  var data = explode("|", $result);
  echo "<tr><td>".$result[0]."</td><td>".$result[1]."</td><td>".$result[2]."</td></tr>";
}
```